# The effect of different time series lengths on correlation

Tags: statistics, time-series

I recently started to learn about time series analysis. I started to wonder how the Length of a time series and viewing only fractions as opposed to the entire series effects correlation.

Let's suppose there are two time series: X and Y of equal length, say 300 days. 
In this case X could be understood as a vector [x1, x2, x3], where x are time series of length 100 days.  The same is true for Y.

Now I can calculate the correlation coefficients for X and Y, lagging X from 0 to 300 i will receive correlation coefficients r_XY. I can then separate r_XY into three different sets[r_XY1; r_XY2;   r_XY3].

I could go on and calculate the correlation coefficient for x1 and y1 and call it r_x1y1. If i do this for all x's and y's i would end up with a vector that looks something like this: [r_x1y1; r_x2y2; r_x3y3].

When I now compare r_XY1 and r_x1y1, I will find that the two are different from each other. This seems intuitively correct to me, however I am struggling to interpret the results the two approaches yield. I am wondering what qualitative difference there is between the information gained by method one (r_XY1) as opposed to method two (r_x1y1). And ultimately when I should decide for which method. 
Thank you all!

I tried comparing the results produced by the two approaches. This has led me to no solid conclusion on my question.